# Android: ArrayAdapter sets TextView date same IF it goes through function

Tags: android

I am making chat application and I created this ArrayAdapter
package helpers;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import als.chaterix.R;

/**
 * Created by arl on 27-Jan-15.
 */
public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List values;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, List values) {
        super(context, R.layout.messagelayout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messagelayout, parent, false);
        TextView sender = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.user);
        TextView date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        TextView messa = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.message);
        sender.setText(((HashMap<String, String>)values.get(position)).get("user_id"));
        ShortcutFunc sf = new ShortcutFunc(this.context);

        try{
        date.setText(sf.FormatDate(((HashMap<String, String>)values.get(position)).get("time")));
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("AdapterTimeError", e.toString());
        }

        messa.setText(((HashMap<String, String>) values.get(position)).get("message"));
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

But this line:

```
try{
            date.setText(sf.FormatDate(((HashMap<String, String>)values.get(position)).get("time")));
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("AdapterTimeError", e.toString());
            }
```

if I use function called FormatDate in my sf (ShortcutFunc) class then date is applied to TextView all same, but if I don't use that function then it's fine but badly formatted.

I am pretty sure it's something to do with position variable but I don't know what.

How do I fix it? I mean it's like date position is stuck on first entry.

Here is the function:

```
public String FormatDate(String date) throws ParseException {
    String turnOut = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    java.util.Date date2 = sdf.parse(date);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date2);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
    Calendar yesterday = Calendar.getInstance();
    yesterday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    yesterday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    yesterday.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    yesterday.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    yesterday.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

    if (c.getTime().equals(new java.util.Date())){
        turnOut = "Today";
    } else if (c.equals(yesterday)) {
        turnOut = "Yesterday";
    } else {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm");
        turnOut  = sdf1.format(date);
    }
    return turnOut;
}
```

Pic of:

```
 Log.d("StackOverflow", ((HashMap<String, String>)values.get(position)).get("time"));
```

[image]

Also something interesting, it's giving exception, what does it mean?

StackTrace:

```
> 01-27 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String
> 01-27 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:296) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> helpers.ShortcutFunc.FormatDate(ShortcutFunc.java:120) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> helpers.ChatAdapter.getView(ChatAdapter.java:44) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:725) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.ListView.correctTooHigh(ListView.java:1414) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1352) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1620) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
> 01-27 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
> 01-27 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 01-27
> 14:15:43.664  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 01-27 14:15:43.664 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 01-27
> 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 01-27
> 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 01-27 14:15:43.674 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 01-27 14:15:43.674 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
> 01-27 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
> 01-27 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434) 01-27
> 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 01-27 14:15:43.674 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 01-27 14:15:43.674 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 01-27
> 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 01-27
> 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 01-27 14:15:43.674 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 01-27 14:15:43.674 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1986) 01-27
> 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1743)
> 01-27 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996) 01-27
> 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5603)
> 01-27 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
> 01-27 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574) 01-27
> 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544) 01-27
> 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
> 01-27 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 01-27 14:15:43.674
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 01-27 14:15:43.674
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 01-27 14:15:43.674 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146) 01-27
> 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-27
> 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 01-27 14:15:43.674 
> 25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
> 01-27 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 01-27
> 14:15:43.674  25244-25244/als.chaterix W/System.err﹕ at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: used `SimpleDateFormat` and apply `DateFormat` what ever you like.

Comment: I am using it, but I am using it in many places so I decided to create function for re-use.

Comment: `FormatDate ()` thows that exception. Where (line) does  the `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown? Can you post the stacktrace in `try { date.setText ( ... ) } catch (Exception e) { e.printStacktrace(); } `

Comment: @sockeqwe I've  updated the question with stacktrace. 
It comes from my Try and Catch within the Adaptor class.

Comment: I have updated my answer. A `y` is missing in `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: @sockeqwe oh right, well I added y, but stacktrace is still the same.
turnOut  = sdf1.format(date); it points me to that.

Comment: `date2` should be the parameter in `sdf1.format(date)`.  Strange that the IDE nor compiler throws an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");` There is a "y" missing (yyyy).
2. In `turnOut  = sdf1.format(date);`: The parameter should be `date2` (Date Object)
3. your listview will lag as hell while scrolling, because you are not recycling the view. check if `convertView != null` and use `ViewHolder` [Recycle Views in adapter](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive)
4. You should consider to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`
5. Does `Today` work?: I mean this statement: `if (c.getTime().equals(new java.util.Date()))` because new Date() creates a new Date object with the current miliseconds of right now when the call happens. If you call it today on 12:51:39 the date object will not equals to a date object created five seconds later.
6. `yesterday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);`: This is not yesterday, this is one month ago.
7. Are you sure / have debugged / printed to logcat the value of 
   `((HashMap<String, String>)values.get(position)).get("time"))`, just to ensure that the value is different from the previous one.

Comment: Well it's taking in Input Date from past and uses it as Today, like what could've happened five minutes ago for example

Comment: Also DAY OF MONTH, isnt that Day? as in 01-31st or so?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. Can you just print the value of `((HashMap<String, String>)values.get(position)).get("time"))`